# Batch script return % symbol

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I'm using a batch script to load a CSV file into MySQL and need to use the following command:

```
EventDate = str_to_date(LEFT(EventDateTimeChar,8), '%Y%m%d')
```

The problem is, the batch file is interpreting the `%Y%` as a variable, when in fact it needs to be submitted verbatim as part of the MySQL command.

Comment: How are you passing this batch file to mysql?

Comment: I've seen this question asked (and answered) several times here but I'm totally unable to find any dupe. Stack Overflow search engine is terrible in general but it specially sucks with symbols (*sigh*)

Comment: @Ravinder - the batch file passes commands to mysql via the mysql stand alone executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within a `cmd` file, you have to use `%%` for a single `%`:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Pax> type qq.cmd
    @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    @echo off

    set xyzzy=plugh
    echo %xyzzy%
    echo %%xyzzy%%

    endlocal

C:\Documents and Settings\Pax> qq
plugh
%xyzzy%
```

Rob van der Woude has an excellent site containing a great many "hidden" features of various different tools, including [this page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) detailing some escape characters.

Comment: No, on the command line you can't escape a `%` with a caret, even `echo %xy^zzy%` works, as it's the variable name which fails to expand then. Therefor it _seems_ to escape anything

Comment: @jeb, it _is_ working (in both cases). Whether you call it escaping or not, the fact remains that the output is as desired: `%xyzzy%` without  substitution. In any case, it's not relevant to the question so I'll remove it.